# Using stetho with okHttp raises java.net.SocketException

Tags: android, okhttp, stetho

I am using facebook's open source project **stetho** to debug my android app. I use okHttp as the http client. The code snippet:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
//builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I comment the second line, I can successfully get the response. However, if I add the second line, exception is raised:

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

Comment: Did you add this line to your gradle?  compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'

Comment: @jj. yes I add the line. Well the problem is addressed magically :-) I think maybe it is the network to be blamed.